# In USA, is it possible to find out how much top people at religious organizations earn?

Tags: united-states, income, finland

This is about people at the highest leadership positions in religious organizations based in United States.

I was reading [this article](http://www.iltasanomat.fi/kotimaa/art-2000001029870.html) (in Finnish language) in a Finnish newspaper that lists the income information reported by leaders of various religious organizations located in Finland.

The reason the newspaper is able to print the information is because tax returns are considered public information in Finland.

Anyway I was curious on whether similar information can be found in USA specifically for religious organizations?

Comment: http://work.chron.com/average-income-pastor-mega-church-9682.html references both Bureau of Labor Statistics as well as a survey for results that may be of interest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about personal finance.

Comment: It would be naive to assume that declared taxable income is the whole story.

Comment: This question seems plausibly enough related to personal finance. People donate to these organizations and may reasonably want to know something about how the money is spent.

Comment: There is no correlation between salary of religious heads and how good the governance is. Even if paid Nil, there are other spends.

Comment: @Brick, if the question is about non-profits and money donated then the question should be framed with all 501(c)(3) organizations in mind and how to screen them. As asked, the question remains off-topic. I'm surprised to see reopen votes with no edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type of organization they are. Non-profit organizations in the US are required to disclose the top 5 salary earners each year in order to maintain their non-profit status.

There are a few sites that can provide this information, but some require a subscription. Alternatively, you can contact the organizations directly and request their latest available tax information under the Freedom of Information Act. Compliance with FOIA is also dependent on what types of funds they receive and from whom.